# XML XSD Validation and Routing in Mule

Tags: java, xsd, mule, xsd-validation

I am new to Mule but have used other products regarding integration.

After receiveing an XML from an file inbound endpoint I want to validate it against an XSD. If validation fails I want to send it to a JMS/VM queue otherwise just proceed with my other already working flow.

I have been able to use a filter and it works as expected. Those not compliant get thrown out in cyberspace. But I want to handle these and return a response.

So what other approach can I go with?

Is there a XML/XSD Router with validation I can use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use include the xsd filter into a message filter, as explained in this [blog post](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/integration-patterns-message-filter/). In this way you will be able to take some other action when the message is filtered.

The simplest solution I can think of would be to throw an exception and to generate the response from a [catch-exception-strategy](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/MULE3USER/Catch+Exception+Strategy)

Comment: Worked fine. Thank you. Had hopes on a more general solution but this works. Sadly it took hours to learn. In my other tool for Integration it took 1 minute. :-(

Comment: @genjosanzo: can you please give an example of xsd filter